# filter SQL incorrect data

Tags: sql, filter, datepart

I cant filter the date and dbo.Items.Condition to A

for the date I need to filter ed.Created to a Year. now I see: "2009-03-11 10:19:25.663"

I would like it to change to Year so that Ii can filter to Year

I changed the code. How Can I just get only the newest records? Now I receive multiple/

```
 SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT h.fullname AS FullName, ep.PropName, i.ItemCode, dbo.Items.Description, ep.CaptionTermId, ed.OldValue, ed.NewValue, YEAR(ed.Created) AS Jaar, i.crdnr, dbo.cicmpy.cmp_name, 
                         ed.Created
FROM            dbo.cicmpy RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ItemAccounts AS i ON dbo.cicmpy.crdnr = i.crdnr LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Items ON i.ItemCode = dbo.Items.ItemCode RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.EbcDataLog AS ed INNER JOIN
                         dbo.EbcProps AS ep ON ed.Property = ep.PropId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.humres AS h ON ed.Creator = h.res_id ON CAST(i.ID AS varchar(36)) = ed.DataKey
WHERE        (i.ItemCode LIKE 'I4107.RHB0029') AND (ep.CaptionTermId = 4850) AND (YEAR(ed.Created) >= 2021)
ORDER BY ep.PropName
```

Comment: As an aside, this query makes my eyes bleed something fierce. Consider replacing all those `CASE WHEN`s with `LEFT JOIN`s on lookup tables and/or a preprocessing step. Your future maintainers (which may include you) will thank you.

Comment: Can't you just use the YEAR() function to get the year part of the dates? Other than that, I agree with @JeroenMostert. The query is not very readable. The mixture of Dutch and English categories doesn't help, either ;)

Comment: I tried I can see the years apart but I cant filter on the year..

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Also add the tag for the dbms used. The above query is product specific.

Comment: I changed the code.. How Can I only receive the newest records instead of 4 / 5